# Error al cambiar el icono de la ventana de tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

En un programa que estoy haciendo en python usando tkinter para la GUI me da el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2109, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icono.ico" not defined
```

En una carpeta tengo el icono de la app y un script con la siguiente función:

```
def getIcono():
    return "icono.ico"
```

(icono.ico es el icono de la app) cuando ejecuto el Main.py es cuando me da el error.

El script que crea la ventana lo tengo en una carpeta diferente al icono, este es el script:

```
from tkinter import Tk

from src.Icon import Icono


class Ventana(Tk):
    def __init__(self, colorDeFondo, tituloVentana, ancho, alto):
        self.colorDeFondo = colorDeFondo
        self.tituloVentana = tituloVentana
        self.ancho = ancho
        self.alto = alto
        super().__init__()
        self.title(self.tituloVentana)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap(Icono.getIcono())
        self.config(bg=self.colorDeFondo)

        self.__CentrarVentana()

    def ActualizarVentana(self):
        self.mainloop()

    def __CentrarVentana(self):
        # Cálculos para el centrado de la ventana
        Ancho_Ventana = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        Alto_Ventana = self.winfo_screenheight()

        Coordenada_X = int((Ancho_Ventana / 2) - (self.ancho / 2))
        Coordenada_Y = int((Alto_Ventana / 2) - (self.alto / 2))

        # Redimensionar Ventana
        return self.geometry(
            "{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self.ancho, self.alto, Coordenada_X, Coordenada_Y)
        )
```

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿tu codigo es solo esa funcion?

Comment: @MARCELOBRAVO si

Comment: porfavor incluye el codigo del otro archivo para poder contestarte ya que la funcion que muestras no tiene ninguna error por lo que solo puede ser causado por el otro codigo con el que interactua.

Comment: @MARCELOBRAVO He editado la pregunta añadiendo el código del script que crea la ventana

Comment: src es el nombre de la carpeta donde se ubica el archivo Icon que contiene la funcion  Icono?

Comment: @MARCELOBRAVO No en src es la carpeta padre, me explico en src tengo 2 subcarpetas una para los scripts (llamada Scripts) y otra para el icono (llamada Icon)

Comment: Pero ya lo he conseguido solucionar

Comment: puede ser que el icono no se encuentra o está dañando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero lo que he hecho es crear un Script en la carpeta en la que tengo el icono en dicho script tengo la siguiente función:

```
from os import chdir
from os.path import dirname


def getIcono():
    chdir(dirname(__file__))
    return "icono.ico"
```

Luego en el script que crea la ventana importo el script que he creado antes, y utilizo la funcion para cambiar el icono y por ultimo vuelvo a establecer el directorio de trabajo en el que se esta ejecutando el script que crea la ventana:

```
from src.Icon import Icono

root.iconbitmap(Icono.getIcono())
chdir(dirname(__file__))
```